# PASSWORD - Password change log

Tags: security, logs, users, password, macos

Is there any way to check all password change logs for one specific user?

I'm using macOS and since its based on Unix, I thought that this could be the place to post this question.

Someone changed my user password and I could get my user back through the appleID and terminal password reset using safe mode.

I want to prove that someone changed my password, while the mac was unlocked.

I tried to use the command `dscl . read /Users/<username> accountPolicyData`, but with it I could only find the last time it was updated - which coincides with my `resetpassword` command execution through the terminal.

I want to check if there is any place where I can see all password changes for a user

Could someone help me?

Comment: It seems like the login and logging is mac-specific. You might have more luck asking there.